# Is there a way to know what functions are called from an external DLL?

Tags: dll, hook, reverse-engineering, monitor

I have an old set of DLLs developed in late 90s with Visual C++ of that time and an application which uses them. Is there any way to know what functions (and their signatures, e.g. arguments and value types) are called from these DLLs.

There's a more general question. Is there a way to monitor all DLL calls which are made by any process in the system?

Answer (score 0):

The only precise way to see what functions are used from a DLL is to debug the application that use the DLL and inspect the stack before each call.
If you want something more generic you can log every LoadLibrary and GetProcAddres API call but it is a daunting task.
You can also run an API monitor software like this one from Rohitab: [APImonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor)